# Getting error into upgrading module

Tags: magento2

I am getting an error while upgrading a module by terminal using the comman:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

The error is:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                               
There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.
```

Could you help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

One of possible reasons may be that filesystem permissions are configured incorrectly. Check if `<project_root>/var` and `<prject_root>/pub/static` are writable by current user.

Another issue may be that your custom module is configured incorrectly see [minimal module configuration example](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-minimal) (broken composer.json or module.xml).